Eigenvalues of the product of diagonalizable matrices
I am trying to understand how I can compute the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}B$ where $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable matrices (in patricular, they are symmetric tridiagonal matrices).
I know that $A$ can be written as $A = Q \Lambda_A Q^T ,$ where $\Lambda_A$ = diag($\lambda_{A_i}$) (contains the eigenvalues of $A$). Furthermore, the eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ can be computed as $\frac{1}{\lambda_{A_i}}$ (reciprocal of the eigenvalues of $A$).
In a similar fashion, $B$ can be written as $B = P \Lambda_B P^T.$
I believe I can then say that $A^{-1}B$ is similar to $\Lambda_{A^{-1}} \Lambda_B$ and its eigenvalues are
$$ \frac{\lambda_{B_i}}{\lambda_{A_i}}.$$
However, I cannot fully get the justification of this right. Any advice?

I suggest you test your idea with some $2 \times 2$ matrices.

Counterexample: $A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \
1& 0
\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\
0& -1
\end{bmatrix}$. Both have real eigenvalues but their product does not.
